# Rails 3 validate uniqueness of one value against a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I have a model with an `active` column, which is a boolean. I want to validate the uniqueness of all newly added records against `company_id`, such that I can add as many records as I want with the same `company_id` to the table so long as `active` is set to `false`. There should only be one `active` record for each `company_id`.

How would I write this? I've already tried:

```
validates :company_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :active }
```

But that seems to also validate against unique combinations of `active` being `false` (such that I can never have more than two `company_id`'s in the table with the same `active` status, regardless of what `active` is)--the validation above allows two records for `company_id`, one with `active = false` and the other with `active = true`. Once those two records are in, the validation blocks everything else.

I then tried adding this:

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)
```

But that doesn't seem to have changed the validation at all (same issue as above).

How can I write this validation so that I can add as many records with the same `company_id` so long as `active` is false, and only allowing one `active = true` per `company_id`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No need to use `validates_each` - that's only if you want to pass multiple attributes through the same block.  Just create a custom validation:

```
validate :company_id_when_active

def company_id_when_active
  if active? and CompanyTerm.exists? ["company_id = ? AND active = 1 AND id != ?", company_id, id.to_i]
    errors.add( :company_id, 'already has an active term')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

Rails 4+ offers a much better solution for this.

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, conditions: -> { where(active: true) }
```

check out [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: How we can write this with the `validates` syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I think I finally figured this out.

Checking up on Rails Guides led me to [validates_each](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_each), which led me to this solution:

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)

validates_each :company do |model, attr, value|
  active = CompanyTerm.active.where(:company_id => value)
  model.errors.add(attr, 'already has an active term') unless active.empty?
end
```

I don't know if that's the most efficient way to write this, but it works. I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but there is the simpliest solution. The answer above is almost correct. You can use `:if` statement as a key like:

```
validates :active, :uniqueness => { :scope => :company_id }, :if => :active
```

Comment: but you still can assign all to `true` using `update_all(:active => false)`

Comment: This is wrong - it checks the value of active on the validating model, not on all other records

Comment: to @koosa: Could you tell me why this is wrong?  if the validation model is inactive(active=false), it's OK not to validate the uniquness of active under the scope of company

Comment: I thinks it's wrong too... because if you have many similar records with same company_id and they are all with (active: false) .... then you try to add a new similer record with the same company_id but this time it's (active: true), you won't be able to add it ... because it will check the uniqueness against all the database even the (active: false) ones, so you will always end up having either many similar records all are inactive, or just one active.... you will never have both

Answer (score 1):

Using [@raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695064/raj) answer with `validates` method:

```rb
validates(
    :company_id,
    uniqueness: { conditions: -> { where(active: true) } }
  )
```

Answer (score -3):

```
validates :company_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :active } unless Proc.new { self.active }
```

And maybe you want to call company itself

```
validates :company, :uniqueness => { :scope => :active } unless Proc.new { self.active }
```

**EDIT**

Following answer based on your solution is a bit more efficient:

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)

validates_each :company do |model, attr, value|
  model.errors.add(attr, 'already has an active term') if CompanyTerm.active.exists?(:company_id => value)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't make my first test case pass, in which I try adding a new record into an empty table with `active` set to `true`, then validating whether or not another new record also with `active` set to `true` is valid or not (both with the same `company_id`). In fact, it seems that the Proc is never called.